# I need to elongate a dataset by filling in dates between two rows in R with a value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lubridate

I'm not sure if this has already been asked but I can't really find it. I have the following kind of dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
   
 d1 <- data.frame(open = rnorm(5), Y = as.Date(c("2020-05-01", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-29")), region = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"))
    
+------------+------------+--------+--+--+
    |    open    |     Y      | region |  |  |
    +------------+------------+--------+--+--+
    | -0.6264538 | 2020-05-01 | a      |  |  |
    | 0.1836433  | 2020-05-08 | a      |  |  |
    | -0.8356286 | 2020-05-15 | a      |  |  |
    | 1.5952808  | 2020-05-22 | a      |  |  |
    | 0.3295078  | 2020-05-29 | a      |  |  |
    +------------+------------+--------+--+--+
```

Now I'd like to turn this into

```
open<-c(rep(d1[1,1],times=7),rep(d1[2,1],times=7),rep(d1[3,1],times=7),rep(d1[4,1],times=7),rep(d1[5,1],times=7))


Y<-seq(from = as.Date("2020-05-01"),to = as.Date("2020-06-04"),by="days")
```

or

```
  +------------+------------+--+--+--+
|    open    |    date    |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+--+--+--+
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-01 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-02 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-03 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-04 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-05 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-06 |  |  |  |
| -0.6264538 | 2020-05-07 |  |  |  |
| 0.1836433  | 2020-05-08 |  |  |  |
| 0.1836433  | 2020-05-09 |  |  |  |
| 0.1836433  | 2020-05-10 |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+--+--+--+
```

So basically, I have data for the beginning of each of several weeks. The 'open' variable applies to each date in between the weeks as well, so I'd like to fill that out and 'elongate' the data in a sense.

In addition, I'd need too do this by group (as in the regions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyr` and `dplyr` you can complete the dates and then fill down.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d1 %>%
  group_by(region) %>% 
  complete(Y = seq.Date(min(Y), max(Y), by = "day")) %>% 
  fill(open, .direction = "down")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach creating a dataframe with the sequence of dates and then merging using `tidyverse` functions and also complete the `NA` values. Here the code for a solution close to what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code for dates
dfdates <- data.frame(Y=seq(min(d1$Y),max(d1$Y),by=1))
#Join and fill
newd1 <- dfdates %>%
  left_join(d1) %>%
  fill(open) %>% select(-region)
```

Output:

```
            Y       open
1  2020-05-01 -0.6264538
2  2020-05-02 -0.6264538
3  2020-05-03 -0.6264538
4  2020-05-04 -0.6264538
5  2020-05-05 -0.6264538
6  2020-05-06 -0.6264538
7  2020-05-07 -0.6264538
8  2020-05-08  0.1836433
9  2020-05-09  0.1836433
10 2020-05-10  0.1836433
11 2020-05-11  0.1836433
12 2020-05-12  0.1836433
13 2020-05-13  0.1836433
14 2020-05-14  0.1836433
15 2020-05-15 -0.8356286
16 2020-05-16 -0.8356286
17 2020-05-17 -0.8356286
18 2020-05-18 -0.8356286
19 2020-05-19 -0.8356286
20 2020-05-20 -0.8356286
21 2020-05-21 -0.8356286
22 2020-05-22  1.5952808
23 2020-05-23  1.5952808
24 2020-05-24  1.5952808
25 2020-05-25  1.5952808
26 2020-05-26  1.5952808
27 2020-05-27  1.5952808
28 2020-05-28  1.5952808
29 2020-05-29  0.3295078
```

If you need to group by `region` you can do that by first filling the variable and then using `group_by()` and completing the `open` variable:

```
#Join and fill 2
newd1 <- dfdates %>%
  left_join(d1) %>%
  fill(region) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  fill(open)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 29 x 3
# Groups:   region [1]
   Y            open region
   <date>      <dbl> <fct> 
 1 2020-05-01 -0.626 a     
 2 2020-05-02 -0.626 a     
 3 2020-05-03 -0.626 a     
 4 2020-05-04 -0.626 a     
 5 2020-05-05 -0.626 a     
 6 2020-05-06 -0.626 a     
 7 2020-05-07 -0.626 a     
 8 2020-05-08  0.184 a     
 9 2020-05-09  0.184 a     
10 2020-05-10  0.184 a     
# ... with 19 more rows
```